# fill as3 array with years

Tags: actionscript-3, range

Is there an easier way to fill an actionscript array with a range of years (let's say 1900 to 2000) than by using a for loop? I thought there'd be some sort of range function, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. A loop is the way to go.

```
var years:Array = [];
for (var i:int = 1900; i < 2000; i++) years.push(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

[!] FAR WORSE SOLUTION THAN THE ACCEPTED ONE [!]

An alternative just for the heck of it:

```
var years : Array = new Array( 100 ).map( function( item : *, index : int, arr : Array ){ 
    return index + 1900;
} );
```

-- EDIT --

This was in no way a serious attempt for a better solution, since IT'S NOT!
It's slower and more memory consuming. I just wondered whether it would be possible with Array#map and found it is. Since I didn't know where to dump this snippet, I posted it here.

Comment: Ah yes, this is much slower and memory consuming. IT IS NO WAY A BETTER SOLUTION THAN THE ACCEPTED ONE. Maybe I should've put a disclaimer. I thought "for the heck of it" was clear enough.